# Change Volume in Cordova/iOs app using Opentok/Tokbox Plugin

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, html5-audio, cordova-plugins

I'm developing a Cordova application that utilizes Tokbox to allow conference calls. It's using the following cordova plugin: https://github.com/songz/cordova-plugin-opentok.

With a little head scratching here and there everything works fine now, except for one thing:

**I can't change the audio volume on iPad and iPhone.**

On Android using the volume keys works. The volume slider on the iPad and the volume buttons on the iPhone do nothing.

Does anyone know how to get it working, or does it work for you without extra effort?

---

What i've tried so far:

- I looked though the opentok.js library and noticed that setting audio
  volume programmatically is not implemented.
- Checked the issue tracker for the opentok plugin to see if this is a known issue.
- Tried several cordova libraries that promise to allow changing the volume of html5 audio/video tag.

Thanks,
Lif

Comment: It would be great if someone could answer with a simple "works for me" or "doesn't work for me".